# восстановление пути bfs c++

Tags: c++

**Задача:**
http://informatics.mccme.ru/mod/statements/view3.php?id=255&chapterid=161
В чем хранить path коня? 
Point path[MAXN] ?

vector< pair > path(MAXN) ?

int path[MAXN][MAXN] ?

Чтобы потом можно было записывать для соседей вершину из который мы пришли(x,y)

**Код:**
http://pastebin.com/RbNNNSbc

Comment: Да как вам удобнее!...

Comment: @Harry изначально я объявлял через Point path[MAXN], но при инициализации path[horse] = tmp; компилятор выдает ошибку "binary '[' : no global operator found which takes type 'Point'... ", tmp здесь типа Point, tmp.x = UNDEF, tmp.y = UNDEF

Comment: Я бы просто хранил узлы, а в узле - координаты и предыдущий, откуда пришел...

Answer (score 2):

Ну вот, такой простенький набросок, ну очень далекий от оптимальности...

```
struct Cell
{
    Cell(int x, int y):x(x),y(y),prev(0),check(false){}
    int x, y;
    Cell* prev;
    bool check;
};

int dx[] = { -2, -2, -1, -1,  1,  1,  2,  2 };
int dy[] = { -1,  1, -2,  2,  2, -2,  1, -1 };

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int N;
    int startx, starty;
    int stopx,  stopy;

    cin >> N >> startx >> starty >> stopx >> stopy;
    startx--; starty--; stopx--; stopy--;

    vector<vector<Cell>> board(N);
    for(int x = 0; x < N; ++x)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < N; ++y)
            board[x].push_back(Cell(x,y));
    }
    queue<Cell*> Q;
    Cell * c = &board[startx][starty];
    c->check = true;
    Q.push(c);
    while(!Q.empty())
    {
        c = Q.front();
        Q.pop();
        for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
        {
            int x = c->x + dx[i];
            int y = c->y + dy[i];
            if (x >= 0 && x < N && y >= 0 && y < N)
            {
                Cell* q = &board[x][y];
                if (q->check) continue;
                q->check = true;
                q->prev = c;
                Q.push(q);
                if (q->x == stopx && q->y == stopy)
                {
                    stack<Cell*> S;
                    do {
                        S.push(q);
                        q = q->prev;
                    } while(q);
                    cout << S.size()-1 << endl;
                    while(!S.empty())
                    {
                        Cell * v = S.top();
                        S.pop();
                        cout << v->x+1 << " " << v->y+1 << endl;
                    }
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```